# In Swift, how do I set every element inside an array to nil?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var roomsLiveStates = [Firebase?]()

for ref in roomsLiveStates {
        if ref != nil {
                ref = nil
            }
        }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: why dont you define your array as optional then, as var roomsLiveStates: [Firebase]? and then assign nil if you want....that will probably make all the items as nil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just set each to `nil`:

```
for index in 0 ..< roomsLiveStates.count {
    roomsLiveStates[index] = nil
}
```

As *The Swift Programming Language* says in its [Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) discussion of `for` syntax:

> This example prints the first few entries in the five-times-table:
>
> ```
> for index in 1...5 {
>     println("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")
> }
> ```
>
> ... In the example above, `index` is a constant whose value is automatically set at the start of each iteration of the loop. As such, it does not have to be declared before it is used. It is implicitly declared simply by its inclusion in the loop declaration, without the need for a `let` declaration keyword.

As this says, the `index` is a constant. As such, you can not change its value.

Comment: timex just looped through each element of array and set the value nil to the element...not in the index of array..that was the problem...but whats the case where i should just loop through array and assign nil to those all elements instead of directly assigning nil to the array ?@MartinR can you explain to me?

Comment: @anishparajuli - You're right to point out that the problem with TIMEX's code was that they were setting the local variable `ref`to nil, not the entries in the array. However, I'm not sure what case you're describing. Rob's code *is* looping through an array and assigning nil to all the elements.

Comment: @anishparajuli - I, too, find this pattern of an array of `nil` values to be highly suspect. I'm hard-pressed to come up with a practical scenario where this wouldn't be better solved with another pattern.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a `map`:

```
roomsLiveStates = roomsLiveStates.map { _ in nil }
```

This is less code and a good habit to get into for other cases where you may want to create a processed copy of an array without mutating the original.

Comment: Or `roomsLiveStates = roomsLiveStates.map { _ in nil }`

Comment: Better, for this situation. Thanks @Rob!

Comment: Do not use this on large arrays, the performance is terrible, you are iterating the array and allocating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to set each element in array to a numberic value(int, float, double ...), you can try `vDSP` framework.

Please check this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/vector_clear_and_fill_functions

Answer (score 1):

You can also just reassign the whole array to one that only contains nil like:

```
roomsLiveStates = [Firebase?](count: roomsLiveStates.count, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Although now that I think about it, this doesn't seem so good, because (probably?) new memory gets allocated which is not fast at all

EDIT: I just checked and found that using `.map` is a lot slower in Debug builds. However on Release builds, `.map` is about 20% faster. So I suggest using the `.map` version (which also is quiet a bit prettier ;)):

```
array = array.map { _ in nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating the array to map it, will result in poor performance (iteration + new allocation).
Allocating the array all over (`init(repeating...`) is better, but still allocates a new array, very costly.
The best way would be to zero out the data without allocating it again, and as every C programmer knows, that's why we have `bzero` and `memset` for.
It won't matter much for small arrays in a non repeating action, and as long as you remember it - using the smallest code possible could make sense, so sometimes using `map` or `init` makes sense.
Final note on the test - `map` and `init` use multiple allocations of the same size in this test, which makes allocation allot faster than in real world usage.
In general, memory allocation is **not** your friend, it is a time consuming process that may result in having to defragment the heap, calling kernel code to allocate new virtual memory, and also must use locks and/or memory barriers.

```swift
import Foundation

guard CommandLine.argc == 2, let size = Int(CommandLine.arguments[1]),size > 0  else {
    fatalError("Usage: \(CommandLine.arguments[0]) {size}\nWhere size > 0")
}

var vector = [Int].init(repeating: 2, count: size)
let ITERATIONS = 1000
var start:Date
var end:Date

start = Date()
for _ in 0..<ITERATIONS {
    vector = vector.map({ _ in return 0 })
}
end = Date()
print("Map test: \(end.timeIntervalSince(start)) seconds")

start = Date()
for _ in 0..<ITERATIONS {
    vector = [Int].init(repeating: 0, count: size)
}
end = Date()
print("init(repeating:,count:) test: \(end.timeIntervalSince(start)) seconds")

start = Date()
for _ in 0..<ITERATIONS {
    let size = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vector[0]) * vector.count // could optimize by moving out the loop, but that would miss the purpose
    vector.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr in
        let ptr = ptr.baseAddress
        bzero(ptr, size)
    }
}
end = Date()
print("bzero test: \(end.timeIntervalSince(start)) seconds")
```

Results when running with an array of 5,000,000 items size (M1 Mac), compiled with optimizations:

```
Map test: 5.986680030822754 seconds
init(repeating:,count:) test: 2.291425108909607 seconds
bzero test: 0.6462910175323486 seconds
```

Edit:
Just realized it's also to initialize the memory using the `initializeMemory(...)` method.
Something like:

```swift
_ = vector.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr in
        ptr.initializeMemory(as: Int.self, repeating: 0)
    }
```

The performance is virtually the same as with `bzero`, and it is pure swift and shorter.