# Which one is better removeAll of Array or initialising the Array again?

Tags: swift

Initializing array again is better than removeAll() of array? What will be the effect on Heap memory in both cases?

Comment: i think remove all is better because if you Initialise a new array that mean you will had two array in memory.
this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333328/how-can-i-deallocate-all-references-elements-from-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are literally the same thing as long as you don't reserve capacity.

Here is the [empty initializer for Array](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bfcdbbd7c2e6647ac39375d560ad02e4f46d20a7/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L806-L808):

```
public init() {
  _buffer = _Buffer()
}
```

Here is [`removeAll`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bfcdbbd7c2e6647ac39375d560ad02e4f46d20a7/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L1266-L1273):

```
public mutating func removeAll(keepingCapacity keepCapacity: Bool = false) {
  if !keepCapacity {
    _buffer = _Buffer()
  }
  else {
    self.replaceSubrange(indices, with: EmptyCollection())
  }
}
```

In both cases, it just creates a new `_Buffer` (which is either `_ArrayBuffer` or `_ContiguousArrayBuffer`), and assigns it to `_buffer`. There is no difference in memory usage or other behavior. `_buffer` is the only property of Array so there is no memory difference between an Array and its buffer (Swift structs have no extra headers). `removeAll()` is implemented as creating a new Array.

If you plan to refill the array to a similar size, then `keepCapacity: true` may prevent some reallocations.